# Get IP from .xml doc In C Program

Tags: c, xml, parsing, doc

Im doing a program in C and i want to get two IPs from this .xml doc.

[image]

I was doing this way but its returning only the first IP:

```
void parseGlobalStats(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {

xmlChar *IP;

    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    cur = cur->next;
    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
   while (cur != NULL)
{
     if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"IP")))
     {
     IP = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
     printf("IP = %s\n",IP);
     }
     return;
}
}
```

It is compiling well but it is returning only the first IP(179.199.24.207) when executed. How can i create a function that get 2 IPs from this doc and store it in a string variable?

Comment: sure your "cur" is initialized?

Comment: nothing to do with the problem, but it is a courtesy to the reader to not write "!strcmp()" but to write "strcmp() == 0". "!" induces "NOT" in ones mind, but you want to induce "EQUALITY"

Comment: "sure your "cur" is initialized?" 90% sure.....I Already change the "!" to "==0".

Comment: to me it looks perferctly luvly. So maybe show us more, like the context of call to "parse()"

Comment: Ok, i'll edit and show to u

Comment: I solve part of this...i will update my question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your while loop contains a unconditional return statement. So you don't technically even have a loop. Also if you would leave it out, you aren't changing the cur inside the loop, so you'd have an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only looking for some global stats (including `IP`), you can use *xpath evaluation*.

Using *xpath*, the following file [ **test.xml** ]:

```
<icestats>
  <source mount="/stream">
    <Listeners>2</Listeners>
    <listener>
      <IP>179.199.24.207</IP>
      <UserAgent>cmus/v2.4.3</UserAgent>
      <Connected>76810</Connected>
      <ID>405</ID>
    </listener>
    <listener>
      <IP>177.133.209.80</IP>
      <UserAgent>WinampMPEG/5.0</UserAgent>
      <Connected>72</Connected>
      <ID>1435</ID>
    </listener>
  </source>
</icestats>
```

can extract `IP` with [ **test.c** ]:

```
/* refactored [minimal changes] from libxml2 tutorials
 * [ http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/apd.html ]
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>

xmlDocPtr getdoc (char *docname) 
{
  xmlDocPtr doc;
  doc = xmlParseFile(docname);

  if (doc == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
    return NULL;
  }

  return doc;
}

xmlXPathObjectPtr getnodeset (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlChar *xpath)
{
  xmlXPathContextPtr context;
  xmlXPathObjectPtr result;

  context = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
  if (context == NULL) {
    printf("Error in xmlXPathNewContext\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  result = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath, context);
  xmlXPathFreeContext(context);
  if (result == NULL) {
    printf("Error in xmlXPathEvalExpression\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  if(xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)){
    xmlXPathFreeObject(result);
    printf("No result\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  char *docname = "test.xml";
  xmlDocPtr doc;
  xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "//IP";
  xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;
  xmlXPathObjectPtr result;
  int i;
  xmlChar *IP;

  doc = getdoc(docname);
  result = getnodeset (doc, xpath);
  if (result) 
  {
    nodeset = result->nodesetval;
    for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) 
    {
      IP = xmlNodeListGetString(
          doc, 
          nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 
          1);
      printf("IP: %s\n", IP);
      xmlFree(IP);
    }
    xmlXPathFreeObject (result);
  }
  xmlFreeDoc(doc);
  xmlCleanupParser();
  return (1);
}
```

sample output:

```
./test 
IP: 179.199.24.207
IP: 177.133.209.80
```

**Further reference**

- [Using XPath to Retrieve Element Content](http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/ar01s05.html)
- http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/apd.html